# How to select only unique latitude and longtitude for one city given multiple options?

Tags: latitude-longitude, geo, dbpedia

I have the following query:

```
PREFIX geo: <http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#>
PREFIX dbpedia-owl: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX dbpedia: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>

SELECT DISTINCT ?person1 ?birthplace1 ?person2 ?birthplace2 
                ?lat1 ?long1 ?lat2 ?long2
WHERE 
{
  ?person1 a dbpedia-owl:Person ;
           dbpedia-owl:birthPlace ?birthplace1 ;
           dbpedia-owl:influenced ?person2 .
  ?person2 dbpedia-owl:birthPlace ?birthplace2 .

  ?birthplace1 a dbpedia-owl:City .
  ?birthplace2 a dbpedia-owl:City .

  optional {
    ?birthplace1 geo:lat ?lat1 .
    ?birthplace1 geo:long ?long1 .

    ?birthplace2 geo:lat ?lat2 .
    ?birthplace2 geo:long ?long2 .
   }
}
```

When I query this in iSparql it pulls out a long list. See [Perma-Link](http://dbpedia.org/isparql/?query=PREFIX%20geo%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2003%2F01%2Fgeo%2Fwgs84_pos&endpoint=/sparql&maxrows=50&timeout=&default-graph-uri=&view=1). I just want an individual lat/long for one city. It doesn't matter which one, I just want a unique one.

Also, can anyone tell me why this doesn't work in Snorql? Thanks.

Comment: Answers to [DBpedia SPARQL query returns multiple and duplicate records](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17174439/dbpedia-sparql-query-returns-multiple-and-duplicate-records/17177749#17177749) show how you can remove duplicate results and get, e.g., unique latitude and longitude for a city.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `GROUP` your results `BY` the persons and birthplaces, and then sample the latitude and longitude values.  This requires only a slight change to your SPARQL query.  There is now

```
GROUP BY ?person1 ?birthplace1 ?person2 ?birthplace2
```

at the bottom, and the projection forms for the latitude and longitude include `SAMPLE`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?person1 ?birthplace1 ?person2 ?birthplace2 
                (SAMPLE(?lat1) as ?lat1) (SAMPLE(?long1) as ?long1)
                (SAMPLE(?lat2) as ?lat2) (SAMPLE(?long2) as ?long2)
```

Here's the whole query:

```
PREFIX geo: <http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#>
PREFIX dbpedia-owl: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX dbpedia: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>

SELECT DISTINCT ?person1 ?birthplace1 ?person2 ?birthplace2 
                (SAMPLE(?lat1) as ?lat1) (SAMPLE(?long1) as ?long1)
                (SAMPLE(?lat2) as ?lat2) (SAMPLE(?long2) as ?long2)
WHERE 
{
  ?person1 a dbpedia-owl:Person ;
           dbpedia-owl:birthPlace ?birthplace1 ;
           dbpedia-owl:influenced ?person2 .
  ?person2 dbpedia-owl:birthPlace ?birthplace2 .

  ?birthplace1 a dbpedia-owl:City .
  ?birthplace2 a dbpedia-owl:City .

  optional {
    ?birthplace1 geo:lat ?lat1 ;
                 geo:long ?long1 .

    ?birthplace2 geo:lat ?lat2 ;
                 geo:long ?long2 .
   }
}
GROUP BY ?person1 ?birthplace1 ?person2 ?birthplace2
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=PREFIX+geo%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2003%2F01%2Fgeo%2Fwgs84_pos%23%3E%0D%0APREFIX+dbpedia-owl%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2F%3E%0D%0APREFIX+dbpedia%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2F%3E%0D%0A%0D%0ASELECT+DISTINCT+%3Fperson1+%3Fbirthplace1+%3Fperson2+%3Fbirthplace2+%0D%0A++++++++++++++++%28SAMPLE%28%3Flat1%29+as+%3Flat1%29+%28SAMPLE%28%3Flong1%29+as+%3Flong1%29%0D%0A++++++++++++++++%28SAMPLE%28%3Flat2%29+as+%3Flat2%29+%28SAMPLE%28%3Flong2%29+as+%3Flong2%29%0D%0AWHERE+%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A++%3Fperson1+a+dbpedia-owl%3APerson+%3B%0D%0A+++++++++++dbpedia-owl%3AbirthPlace+%3Fbirthplace1+%3B%0D%0A+++++++++++dbpedia-owl%3Ainfluenced+%3Fperson2+.%0D%0A++%3Fperson2+dbpedia-owl%3AbirthPlace+%3Fbirthplace2+.%0D%0A%0D%0A++%3Fbirthplace1+a+dbpedia-owl%3ACity+.%0D%0A++%3Fbirthplace2+a+dbpedia-owl%3ACity+.%0D%0A%0D%0A++optional+%7B%0D%0A++++%3Fbirthplace1+geo%3Alat+%3Flat1+%3B%0D%0A+++++++++++++++++geo%3Along+%3Flong1+.%0D%0A%0D%0A++++%3Fbirthplace2+geo%3Alat+%3Flat2+%3B%0D%0A+++++++++++++++++geo%3Along+%3Flong2+.%0D%0A+++%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0AGROUP+BY+%3Fperson1+%3Fbirthplace1+%3Fperson2+%3Fbirthplace2&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=30000&debug=on)