# dbpedia SPARQL - how to get country from latitude and longitude

Tags: sql, sparql, dbpedia

I am using this [dbpedia query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17177749/1506363) to fetch Museums from `dbpedia`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?Museum
  (SAMPLE(?name) as ?name)
  (SAMPLE(?abstract) as ?abstract)
  (SAMPLE(?thumbnail) as ?thumbnail)
  (MAX(?latitude) as ?latitude)
  (MAX(?longitude) as ?longitude)
  (SAMPLE(?photoCollection) as ?photoCollection)
  (SAMPLE(?website) as ?website)
  (SAMPLE(?homepage) as ?homepage)
  (SAMPLE(?wikilink) as ?wikilink)
WHERE { 
  ?Museum a dbpedia-owl:Museum ; 
          dbpprop:name ?name ; 
          dbpedia-owl:abstract ?abstract ; 
          dbpedia-owl:thumbnail ?thumbnail ; 
          geo:lat ?latitude ;  
          geo:long ?longitude ; 
          dbpprop:hasPhotoCollection ?photoCollection ;
          dbpprop:website ?website ; 
          foaf:homepage ?homepage ; 
          foaf:isPrimaryTopicOf ?wikilink .
  FILTER(langMatches(lang(?abstract),"EN")) 
  FILTER (langMatches(lang(?name),"EN"))
}
GROUP BY ?Museum
LIMIT 20
```

My objective is to include `Continent` of each returned record. Optionally I like to have `Country` too, but that's not required.

Each of the returned `Museum` object has dbpedia-owl:location entry, but they are not necessarily having country. Plus, it has multiple values, so they are not useful.

Is there a way to fetch Continent value from latitude (`geo:lat`) and longitude (`geo:long`)?

Or do I need another query (or subquery) to fetch this data?

**UPDATE:**

I saw couple of options lately.
First - if country requirement is fulfilled, continent is easily achievable - I can just embed the mapping into my client side code.

Second - there are many (non-dbpedia, non-sparql) ways to achieve what I want, like [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-reverse), [this](http://thematicmapping.org/engine/) and [this](http://download.geonames.org/export/dump/). The last two I mention are ways to get country value from a local DB lookup.

But querying a webservice or having 3+ MB database - both are sort of overkill to get a continent/country value from coords, and given the vast nature of dbpedia objects I find it easy to believe that it exists somewhere. And that is the kind of solution I am looking for.

Comment: In general, the most reliable way to determine the structure of data in DBpedia is to browse the data, follow the links, and see if you can find a way to get what you're looking for.  Then, code it up and see if you get _enough_ results.  if you don't, look at the cases where you don't get results, and see what the data says about them.  Repeat this process until you've got what you want.  It's unfortunate, sometimes, that the data isn't more regular, but that's also one of the benefits of open-ended knowledge representation.

Comment: (That said, this is kind of an interesting problem, and I'm browsing some data now. :))

Comment: thanks @Joshua (calling you now by first name as we have gone quite long :-)). Basically, post-dbpedia processing, I can always ask webservices that does this, but that is an overkill for a continent. Also see my update.

Comment: Responding to your first comment, I think I already mentioned that country is not a field in any Museums that I get. I looked for it in location, but it is highly inconsistent and a rare incident that I find a country there. My answer is NO - there is not enough data if I rely on it.

Comment: Browsing the data is more than just browsing the properties of the particular resource you're looking at.  For instance, the Burnaby  Village Museum has `dbpedia-owl:location dbpedia:Canada`.  If `dbpedia:Canada` had a value for a hypothetical `dbpedia-owl:Continent` property, you could do something like `?museum dbpedia-owl:location [ dpbedia-owl:Continent ?continent ]`.  The information may be a few layers deep, and you might need something like property chains to retrieve it.

Comment: But there is no guarantee Canada is one of the locations. This itself reduces major chunk of rows I receive.

Comment: Correct: there is no such guarantee.  My point was that if you want to do this based on the `dbpedia-owl:location` property, you'll need to consider the kinds of things that can be the value of that property, and what kind of properties those things might have.  You might, then, end up with something like `?museum dbpedia-owl:location ?location . { ?location a dbpedia:Country ; dbpedia-owl:Continent ?contie } UNION { ?location ... }` where `...` is some other pattern to handle some other cases.  If you want to do it based _just_ the data, you'll probably have to cover a few cases.

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to do this in DBpedia alone for these reasons:

- it doesn't have a consistent way of designating location. Eg I find 5341 `dbo:Museum` but only 4931 have `dbo:location`

`select count(*) {
  ?x a dbo:Museum.
  filter exists {?x dbo:location []}
}`

- it doesn't have a consistent place hierarchy. Eg there's no statement that Bulgaria and France are in Europe (there's a category European_Union and a YAGO type to the same effect, but that's different)
- there's no region info, and I'm not sure the DBpedia endpoint has a GeoSPARQL index

Furthermore, the DBpedia info is very incomplete because:

- it relies on people using the infobox Museum.
- it has data only from English Wikipedia

In contrast, Wikidata knows about 23528 museums: click https://tools.wmflabs.org/sqid/#/view?id=Q33506 **and wait** a few seconds until it fetches the stats. 23528 is the total number of unique instances of this class (Museum) and its 126 direct and indirect subclasses (eg Military Museum)